# macro has not been expanded - circe macro - solution found already

Tags: scala, scala.js, scala-macros, circe

At [this](https://github.com/jhegedus42/IM_shared_2018_11_22/blob/64ccc2698b1987ffc97959809b7595340a6bb93f/layer_V_JS_client/src/main/scala/app/client/rest/commands/generalCRUD/GetEntityAJAX.scala#L34) line I get a compiler error :

`macro has not been expanded`.

Here is the code snippet :

```
package app.client.rest.commands.generalCRUD

import app.shared.data.model.Entity.{Data, Entity}
import app.shared.data.model.{DataType, LineText, User}
import app.shared.data.ref.{Ref, RefDyn, RefVal, RefValDyn}
import app.shared.rest.routes.crudRequests.GetEntityRequest
//import app.shared.rest.routes.crudRequests.GetEntityRequest.GetEntityReqResult
import app.shared.{SomeError_Trait, TypeError}
import io.circe
import io.circe.Decoder
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.parser.decode
import org.scalajs.dom.ext.Ajax

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scalaz.\/

object GetEntityAJAX {


  import scala.scalajs.concurrent.JSExecutionContext.Implicits.queue

  def getEntity[E <: Entity : ClassTag ](ref: Ref[E])(implicit d:Decoder[RefVal[E]]):
  Future[RefVal[E]] = {
    import scala.scalajs.concurrent.JSExecutionContext.Implicits.queue
    val route: String =GetEntityRequest.queryURL(ref)

//    val route: String = ???

    val res: Future[RefVal[E]] = Ajax
                                 .get( route )
                                 .map( _.responseText )
                                 .map( decode ) <======= COMPILER ERROR - MACRO NOT EXPANDED 
                                 .map((x: Either[circe.Error, RefVal[E]]) => x.right.get) //backlog
//    .map( x:RefVal[E] => GetEntityReqResult[E] )
    ??? //todo
    res
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record I found the solution :

```
  import scala.scalajs.concurrent.JSExecutionContext.Implicits.queue

  def getEntity[E <: Entity : ClassTag ](ref: Ref[E])(implicit d:Decoder[RefVal[E]]):
  Future[RefVal[E]] = {
    import scala.scalajs.concurrent.JSExecutionContext.Implicits.queue
    val route: String =GetEntityRequest.queryURL(ref)

//    val route: String = ???

    def dd(s:String) : Either[circe.Error, RefVal[E]]= decode(s)

    val res: Future[RefVal[E]] = Ajax
                                 .get( route )
                                 .map( _.responseText )
                                 .map( x=>dd(x) )
                                 .map((x: Either[circe.Error, RefVal[E]]) => x.right.get) //backlog
//    .map( x:RefVal[E] => GetEntityReqResult[E] )
    ??? //todo
    res
  }
```